# Activate all configs after installing Update Package

Tags: update-packages

After installing a Sitecore Update Package via the Update Installation Wizard, there is still a manual step required to active any config files that would be overwritten. Does anyone have a script or other means of activating them all quickly, for cases where you are confident in your config management?

Comment: Nick, never tried it but we might be able to do something with post deployment step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this quickly using PowerShell, without any new tools, see snippet below. It will handle dated packages generated by TDS as well.

```powershell
# use name of package without .update extension
$packageName = "MyPackage"
get-childitem -recurse -filter "*.config.$($packageName)*" | ? {$_.FullName -notmatch "\\temp\?"} | % { Move-Item $_.FullName $_.FullName.Substring(0, $_.FullName.LastIndexOf(".")) -Force }
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the [Sitecore Package Deployer](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2015/september/sitecore-package-deployer.aspx)? You basically upload the .update package to a specific folder, it installs it, and then does that whole config activation. I've been using this for my production deploys now for 9 months and it saves so much time and hassle.

Comment: Jason this would require TDS?

Comment: As far as I know it's a free GitHub project that just runs .update packages. The install is a config file and some binaries, from my recollection. I don't believe you need any TDS dlls, but since we use TDS, hard for me to be sure...

Comment: @JayS You are correct, this module is not dependent on TDS, as update packages are a built-in Sitecore feature.